# Drawing mazes with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, pstricks

I need to know if there is some Tex package that would allow me to draw these kinds of mazes (though preferably 3D):

http://www.ratbehavior.org/RatsAndMazes.htm

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I am not aware of any package that specialized on mazes. However, you can draw these with Ti*k*Z or pstricks. If you need "real" 3D, asymptote may what you're looking for.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a package, font, tool, book or other off-site resource** are off-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it.